# GridDB: How to resolve 'Container not found' error when accessing a container in GridDB database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, griddb

I'm trying to access a container in my GridDB database using Node.js and the griddb-node package. However, I'm encountering a `Container not found` error even though I have confirmed that the container exists. What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

```js
const griddb = require('griddb-node');

try {
  const factory = griddb.StoreFactory.getInstance();
  const store = factory.getStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 31810,
    clusterName: 'defaultCluster',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin'
  });

  const container = store.getContainer('nonexistentContainer');

  // Perform operations on the container

  container.close();
  store.close();
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Container not found error:', error);
}
```